# Variable not found onPress React-Native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react and i'm trying to run a simple function in onPress method of a button but when i'm trying to load the page where the button is located it return error "unable to find variable 'test'"

Here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layout, Button, Text  } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';

export default class Settings extends React.Component {

test(){
      fetch('http://192.168.100.160:3000/prenotazioni')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(users => console.warn(users))
}

render(){
  return (
  <Layout style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: "center"}}>
    <Text>Sei nelle Settings</Text>
    <Button onPress={test}>MySQL</Button>
  </Layout>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: try `this.test()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onPress={this.test}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add `onPress={this.test}` instead. As shown below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Layout, Button, Text  } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';

export default class Settings extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.test = this.test.bind(this);
 }

test(){
      fetch('http://192.168.100.160:3000/prenotazioni')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(users => console.warn(users))
}

render(){
  return (
  <Layout style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: "center"}}>
    <Text>Sei nelle Settings</Text>
    <Button onPress={this.test}>MySQL</Button>
  </Layout>
  );
}
}
```